# Crystal lang. How to realize pattern producer-consumer with a few producers?

Tags: fifo, crystal-lang

A few days ago I asked [Does it have a crystal-lang Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128133/does-it-have-a-crystal-lang-queue), and @Johannes Müller answered me for using `Channel::Buffered(T)`. Now, I have a littlebit another question. What if I have more than one producer? And all of them using the same `Channel`?

For example:

```
channel = Channel(String).new

# first producer
spawn do
  5.times do |i|
    puts "first producer #{i}"
    channel.send "first #{i}"
    sleep 0.1
  end
end

# second producer, that send data to the same with first producer channel
spawn do
  5.times do |i|
    puts "second producer #{i}"
    channel.send "second #{i}"
    sleep 0.1
  end
end

# consumer
spawn do
  loop do
    data = channel.receive
    puts "receive: #{data}"
    sleep 0.5
  end
end

sleep 6
```

Output will be:

```
$ crystal ./test.cr
first producer 0 # ok. first produced 0
second producer 0 # ok. second produced 0
receive: first 0 # ok. received from the first producer
first producer 1 # o_O. Where received data from the second producer?
receive: first 1 
first producer 2
receive: first 2
first producer 3
receive: first 3
first producer 4
receive: first 4
receive: second 0 # aa. It's here... Why it's happend only, when the first producer was produced all?
second producer 1 
receive: second 1
second producer 2
receive: second 2
second producer 3
receive: second 3
second producer 4
receive: second 4
```

As you can see, the "second producer" send first package almost at the same time with the first, but it's was ignored untill the first producer finished the job. And doesn't matter, channel buffered or not.

Why did not they work consistently? If the first producer, works in an eternal cycle, data from the second producer never been received.

Probably this behavior should be, and send data to one place from several - obviously bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **[Read the docs!](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/guides/concurrency.html)**

Not sure if i properly understood what you meant, but is this the expected output?:

```
First producer sent: 0
Consumer received "First: 0"!
Second producer sent: 0
Consumer received "Second: 0"!
First producer sent: 1
Consumer received "First: 1"!
Second producer sent: 1
Consumer received "Second: 1"!
First producer sent: 2
Consumer received "First: 2"!
Second producer sent: 2
Consumer received "Second: 2"!
First producer sent: 3
Consumer received "First: 3"!
Second producer sent: 3
Consumer received "Second: 3"!
First producer sent: 4
Consumer received "First: 4"!
Second producer sent: 4
Consumer received "Second: 4"!
```

---

If so; this is the code:

```
class CrystalIsAwesome
  @@products = 0
  @@channel = Channel(String).new

  def self.produce(which, times, produce_time = 0)
    @@products += times
    spawn do
      times.times do |i|
        puts "#{which} producer sent: #{i}"
        @@channel.send "#{which}: #{i}"
        sleep produce_time.seconds
        end
    end
  end

  # first producer
  produce "First", 5

  # second producer
  produce "Second", 5

  @@products.times do |_|
    puts %(Consumer received "#{@@channel.receive}"!)
  end
end
```

Try adding a third producer (`produce "Third", 2, 1`) and see how it plays out.

Again; see [the Concurrency docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/guides/concurrency.html) for why this works like this.

Comment: thank you for update your answer. Version with macro very interesting! Now I understand a littlebit what is going on here. As you may see, english lang i don't know very well and I miss some important things from the documentation

Comment: Glad to be of help @qpi, wasn't too happy with the first answer (was late at night). The code can still be much better probably, i am also quite new to crystal, good luck with whatever you are doing.

Comment: You don't need a macro do do that, macros are not meant to be used that way.. use a normal method in a module for example, and use a constant or class varia le to hold the list of producers.

Comment: Thanks @bew! Corrected. Thinking back i don't know what i was thinking when using macros. Anything else i'm missing (or, of course; but anything important)?